# Exit Code 1 Error after building iOS Application

Tags: objective-c, ios, build, restkit

I am trying to build my project with RestKit, when I build it I get the error below. I have tried compiling using Apple LLVM 3.0 and LLVM GCC 4.2 and both produce the same result. Any have any ideas what is causing this issue?

```
Ld "/Users/Jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Line-dmzyzxolztfnmyeuzqkqcinpsoeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Line.app/Line" normal i386
    cd "/Jim/Documents/Xcode Projects/Line"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk "-L/Users/Jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Line-dmzyzxolztfnmyeuzqkqcinpsoeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/Jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Line-dmzyzxolztfnmyeuzqkqcinpsoeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Users/Jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Line-dmzyzxolztfnmyeuzqkqcinpsoeq/Build/Intermediates/Line.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Line.build/Objects-normal/i386/Line.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework Security -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -lxml2 "/Users/Jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Line-dmzyzxolztfnmyeuzqkqcinpsoeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a" -framework CoreData -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/Jim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Line-dmzyzxolztfnmyeuzqkqcinpsoeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Line.app/Line"

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: You dont see any error message?

Comment: That is the only thing that is being displayed.

Comment: That is weird. Does running the command `cd "/Jim/Documents/Xcode Projects/Line" && MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6  PATH="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" ...the clang command.. ` in a terminal give any more information?

Comment: Is `/Jim/Documents/Xcode Projects/Line` really correct? i guess `cd` should exit with status 1 if the directory does not exist.

Comment: Yes, I can CD to that directory just fine.

Comment: And running the commands in a terminal did not give anything more? (`echo $?` shows exit code 1?). Also try to add `-v` to the clang command for more verbose output.

Comment: did you tried deleting the derived data directory?

Comment: I had this same problem all of yesterday and today. I finally did get it working but I don't know what the specific problem was. I just downloaded the latest stable release from restkit.org and followed the instructions in the readme file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

atrljoe:
did you build RestKit  according to the wiki page "Installing RestKit in Xcode 4.x" on github.com/RestKit?  i think there is a little mistake.
here is my solution:
1. in "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary  With Libraries", delete the RestKit.framework and add Security.frameWork
2. build again

then it works.