# build RestKit failed with Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, restkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exit Code 1 Error after building iOS Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386551/exit-code-1-error-after-building-ios-application)

i wanted to install RestKit in my Xcode 4.2 according to the wiki page ["Installing RestKit in Xcode 4.x"](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x), but always got the build error

> "Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1"